# how can in a given array n squared can be printed in a pattern as shown in the below?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

this is my code to write a method that takes length n squared (n*n) and fill the array with the following pattern. Return the array at the end and print it.

```
input:n=4 
output: {0, 0, 0, 1,   0, 0, 2, 1,    0, 3, 2, 1,   4, 3, 2, 1}
```

(spaces have been added to show four distinct groups).

how can it be written in for loop instead of while loop?

```
def arrays(n):
    nsquared = n*n
    temp = [0]*nsquared

    i = 1
    while i <= n:
        j = 1
        while j<= i:
            arrays[(i*n)-j] = j  #this line is showing error

            j += 1
        i += 1
    return arrays


n = int(input("Please input a number: n= "))
print(arrays(n))
```

Comment: Your comment in the code says your code runs into an error - is that why you're considering to change the `while` into a `for`? `for` loops are well suited to the problem, but what have you tried yourself? Are you asking how to write a `for`-loop at all? What problem did you run into trying to write one?

Comment: Note that the error is simply a matter of you trying to index `arrays`, which is the name of your function. You were perhaps trying to access `temp` instead? And then to `return temp` as well?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code using `for` loop. Start looking from the end to start you can find the pattern.

Modified the source code provided by you and here we are instead of using `while` we are using `for` loop.

This line is show error because   `arrays[(i*n)-j] = j` `arrays` is the name of the function. The `arrays` must be a `list`.

```
def arrays(n):
    nsquared = n*n
    temp = [0]*nsquared

    for i in range(1, n+1):
        for j in range(1, i+1):
            temp[(i*n)-j] = j
    return temp


n = int(input("Please input a number: n= "))
print(arrays(n))
```